# How to hide CAF notification

Tags: chromecast, google-cast, custom-receiver

I am developing an app and using a custom Chromecast Receiver CAF v3. I have managed to show a notification when playing media on the Chromecast receiver. And I can also update the notification by setting data such as title and image by calling

`playerManager.setMediaInformation(mediaInformation, true)`

But how do I hide the notification when stopping playback, but still being connected to the Chromecast?

I have tried setting `mediaInformation.metadata = undefined` and calling `playerManager.setMediaInformation(mediaInformation, true)`, but that does not work.

I can't seem to find information about this anywhere